# STM32L0 Read out protection example code?

Tags: c, eclipse, stm32

I want to prevent my code from being read out, and I have seen on the internet that STM32 has a feature for doing this. However I failed to find some example code, and also I do not understand how to use it ?

- Should I place the read out protection function READ_PROTECTION() at the beginning before calling my main code ? or
- Should I place it at the end after calling my main code ?

An example code for this would be really helpful for me.

Thanks.

Comment: [This ST application note](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/89/12/c5/e2/0d/0e/45/7f/DM00186528.pdf/files/DM00186528.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00186528.pdf) describes all you need.

Comment: Hi @LPs, the read out protection level 0/1/2 seems to fit well what I need, i have seen built in function like _FLASH_OB_RDPConfig(OB_RDP_Level_1);_ which performs the read out protection but unfornately I cant find an good example for using this function.

Comment: So, you are looking for ready-to-use solution. You like easy win... ;) You should try to improve your skills understanding the usage of those feature and try to write something on your own. In case of problem you can post question on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STM32 flash memory consist of 2 memory regions: first write-read protected, second read protected. See [this](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/de/33/b4/5d/8a/55/45/97/DM00033344.pdf/files/DM00033344.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00033344.pdf) for reference. All you need is to write proper linker script that loads your code into proper memory region and sets proper option bytes. How to do this look [here](http://developers.stf12.net/cpp-demo/gcc-linker-script-and-stm32-a-tutorial). And how to include linker file to eclipse see [here](https://mcuoneclipse.com/2016/11/01/getting-the-memory-range-of-sections-with-gnu-linker-files/#more-19909).

EDT: [Here](https://my.st.com/public/STe2ecommunities/mcu/Lists/cortex_mx_stm32/Flat.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fpublic%2FSTe2ecommunities%2Fmcu%2FLists%2Fcortex%5Fmx%5Fstm32%2Fflash%20readback%20protection&FolderCTID=0x01200200770978C69A1141439FE559EB459D7580009C4E14902C3CDE46A77F0FFD06506F5B&currentviews=1948) is example of how to set option bytes directly from your code with functions mentioned in your post (see **clive1** post) those functions seem to be part of mbed library (see [this](https://developer.mbed.org/users/hes/code/mbed-src/docs/tip/group__FLASH__Group3.html) for reference). This code needs to be executed form your `main` function. [Here](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/programming_manual/10/98/e8/d4/2b/51/4b/f5/CD00283419.pdf/files/CD00283419.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00283419.pdf) is some useful information about option byte programming from controller code.

Comment: Hi @nopasara, I had a quick look to the links you provided above, they're quite hard for me to understand since I don't have a good basic knowledge in Linker script. 
I have searched on the internet and there are some built in function in STM32 to achieve read out protection level 0/1/2 like _FLASH_OB_RDPConfig(OB_RDP_Level_1);_. This function seems to fullfil well what i need, unfortunately there is no example how to use them.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add it into the code as code may change or you may miscalculate the sectors to be non readable. After flashing your code , you can use [ST Link utility](http://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stsw-link004.html) to select the particular section of your flash memory and set the readout protection on your code.

Comment: How can the OP use STM32 ST-Link Utility to do that?

Comment: ST Link utility provides you GUI to configure different protections. by ST link utility , you can select each sector of Flash memory and assign different protections to it. Like sector 1 : No protection, Sector 2: level 1 protection etc

Answer (score 1):

You can enable and disable Read Out Protection by code.
But i recommend use software "stm32 Flash loader" or "ST Link utility" to do this instead.
see tutorial [here](http://www.arm.vn/TinChiTiet/tabid/105/id/120/Default.aspx).
To disable Read Out Protection just Mass erase flash.